# Avoiding for loops and changing and plotting scales in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data set example: Dataset where I travelled from A to B to C or in reverse order. I would like to plot my travel path which I have done according to the code below. Additionally I would like have the y-scale somewhat so it shows that the distance between B and C is bigger than A and B. On travel route can be assumed to be equal for all. Also, I would appreciate some feedback and alternative solutions for my loop.

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Checkpoint = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3),
                 Route = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 3)),
                 Times = as.POSIXct(c("4:10", "4:25", "5:00", "8:00", "8:22", 
                                      "9:00","10:00", "10:15", "10:50"), format = "%H:%M"))

df[7:9,1]  <- rev(df[7:9,1])

# If travelled from A to C, then F1, F2

df$Direction <- NA

for(i in 1:length(levels(df$Route))){

  y <- which(df$Route == i)
  x <- filter(df, Route == i)

  l <- ifelse(x[x$Checkpoint == "A", "Times"]  < x[x$Checkpoint == "B", "Times"], "F1", "F2")

  df$Direction[y] <-l

} ; rm(y,x,l,i)


ggplot(df, aes(x=Times, color = Route, y= Checkpoint, group=Route))  +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_light()
```

Comment: where are you using Direction while plotting?

Comment: I'm not sure what this plot is for, but instead of changing scales, wouldn't it be more logical to obtain the distances between checkpoints (even rough estimates) and plot distance (x) against time (y)?

Comment: @Wave Exactly, that is what I want to do. But I still want to have the checkpoints A/B/C on the Y axis.

Comment: "where are you using Direction while plotting?" I dont, did not think about it, but I'm using it later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
diff <- df[1:3,]
diff$time <- diff$Times - diff$Times[1]
diff <- diff[,c(1,5)]

df <- merge(df, diff)
df$time <- as.numeric(df$time)


ggplot(df, aes(x=Times, color = Route, y= time, group=Route))  +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(df$time), labels = c("A","B","C")) +
  theme_light()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `for loop` by the following code using `split`, it should be faster since you don't need to `subset` your data iteratively multiple times inside the loop,

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Route), 
       function(x) {
         x['Direction'] <- ifelse(x[x['Checkpoint'] == "A", "Times"]  < x[x['Checkpoint'] == "B", "Times"], "F1", "F2")
         x}))
```

It should give you the following same output.

```
    Checkpoint Route               Times Direction
1.1          A     1 2017-01-31 04:10:00        F1
1.2          B     1 2017-01-31 04:25:00        F1
1.3          C     1 2017-01-31 05:00:00        F1
2.4          A     2 2017-01-31 08:00:00        F1
2.5          B     2 2017-01-31 08:22:00        F1
2.6          C     2 2017-01-31 09:00:00        F1
3.7          C     3 2017-01-31 10:00:00        F2
3.8          B     3 2017-01-31 10:15:00        F2
3.9          A     3 2017-01-31 10:50:00        F2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the plyr package and do this in one line:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,c('Route'),transform,Direction=ifelse(Times[3]>Times[1]&Checkpoint[1]=='A','A->C','C->A'))


   Checkpoint Route               Times Direction
    1          A     1 2017-01-30 04:10:00      A->C
    2          B     1 2017-01-30 04:25:00      A->C
    3          C     1 2017-01-30 05:00:00      A->C
    4          A     2 2017-01-30 08:00:00      A->C
    5          B     2 2017-01-30 08:22:00      A->C
    6          C     2 2017-01-30 09:00:00      A->C
    7          C     3 2017-01-30 10:00:00      C->A
    8          B     3 2017-01-30 10:15:00      C->A
    9          A     3 2017-01-30 10:50:00      C->A
```